# Does the user need special permissions to call a package using LoadFromSqlServer?

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

when calling a SSIS package (C# app) using LoadFromSqlServer, does the user account have to have any special permissions on the database or server?

I can't seem to view the packages in EM at the moment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to grant some rights to the users which need to run the SSIS packages.

[This page](http://sqljunkies.com/WebLog/knight_reign/archive/2006/01/05/17769.aspx) should provide the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer exactly, but where an SSIS package is run from is important.  If I run it from Visual Studio, it's using my account and permissions.  If I load it to the server and just try to run the package directly, it's using something else (and usually fails because of they way our servers are set up).  If I run it from a job on the server, it uses the server SQA account, with the permissions from that account.